# Best way how to describe "ModelAttribute" with Swagger

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

I am trying to integrate Swagger2 to my Spring Boot based application. The issue is that swagger does not consider model attributes.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/events", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public PagedResources<EventResource> getEvents(
        @Valid SearchCriteria searchQuery, 
        BindingResult result, 
        PageableResourcesAssembler<EventResource> assembler){

    // code
}
```

As you can see `SearchCriteria` is a class which gets automatically binded by Spring.

```
public class SearchCriteria {

    private List<EventType> eventTypes;

    private LocalDateTime from;

    // getters setters
}
```

But what swagger generates is following:

[image]

which is not expected. The desired result might be generated by annotation `getEvents` method by

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "eventTypes", paramType = "query"),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "from", paramType = "query")
})
PagedResources<EventResource> getEvents(@ApiParam(hidden = true ) @Valid SearchCriteria searchQuery
```

but the `@ApiParam(hidden = true )` does not work, because in the Swagger UI is the `searchQuery` parameter still present.

---

What is the proper way how to describe request parameters contained in a POJO using swagger? To me the best way would by annotation `SearchCriteria` class with `@ApiModel` but it does not work.

Comment: what springfox version?

Comment: @jmattheis I am been using `2.6.1` and Spring boot `1.5.X`

Comment: @PeterJurkovic This should be fixed in an upcoming 2.7.0 release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This [bug](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1778) was fixed in [Springfox v2.7.0](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/releases/tag/2.7.0).**

---

*Original Answer:*

The `@Valid`-annotation actually does that the param will be seen as body-param.

As this shouldn't do this [I've opened an issue on the springfox github page](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1778).

> but the @ApiParam(hidden = true ) does not work

Springfox provides for that the `springfox.documentation.annotations.ApiIgnore`-annotation which should work.

Like written in [this issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1139) using the annotation from springfox is the right way.

Comment: Thanks for raising the bug.